# Eclipse: import Java compiler preferences only for project

Tags: java, eclipse, epf

I have altered the Java compiler settings in my workspace, exported these settings as epf file and resetted the compiler settings workspace wide back to its default. Because I want these settings only in 2 projects in my workspace.

Now, how can I achieve this, importing the epf file for only one project? I am aware of the „enable project specific settings“ option and enabled it and right clicked on the project, imported the epf file but nothing happened. Neither did it change the compiler settings for the project nor for the whole workspace.

If I import it via file menu it works for the whole workspace. I want to share it with a colleague and not go through each option step by step (there are just too many) and using these settings for the whole workspace is insufficient because it then generates about 2000 errors.

I guess it is possible since it has an extra import settings option when right clicking on a project.

Comment: Is multiple workspaces out of the question?

Comment: yes it is out of question

Comment: that's unfortunate. it solves a lot of problems, and probably saves you a lot of time.